# Проверка числа на целочисленность С++

Tags: c++

Пишу программу на статистику, и мне необходимо посчитать квартили. 
Проблема состоит в том что всё время проходит установка `else`, и непонятно, почему код не работает:

В моём случае `n=130` и на `i=2` и `i=4`должно срабатывать

`tmp == (ceil(tmp)-1)` округляем к большему и отнимаем единицу

```
void KvartilC(vector<int>&X,float n)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        float tmp = (i*n) / 4; // если число целое то подходит, если нет то 
                                                            //квартиля нет

        if (tmp == (ceil(tmp)-1)) // проверка на целочисельность
        {
            cout <<"Qvartil_"<<i<<" : "<< X[tmp]<< endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Ne isnuje Qvartila_"<<i<< endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А n реально должно быть float или на самом деле оно целое?

Comment: @MBo, целое, я думал что причина целочисленное деление

Comment: Тогда незачем возиться с вещественными и округлением,  достаточно проверить, что `(i*n)%4==0` или `(i*n)&3==0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А просто посчитать и посмотреть что мешает?

```
float n = 130;
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    float tmp = (i*n) / 4;
    cout << "tmp = " << tmp << "  ceil.. = " << (ceil(tmp)-1) << endl;
}
```

дает

```
tmp = 32.5  ceil.. = 32
tmp = 65  ceil.. = 64
tmp = 97.5  ceil.. = 97
tmp = 130  ceil.. = 129
```

Еще вопросы есть? :) Прочтите внимательно, **как** [`ceil`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) выполняет округление...

Comment: Лол, спасибо.  Я думал что `ceil` закругляет только дробные числа. А как ещё можна проверить число на целочисельноть? Может функция есть какая в С++

Comment: Использовать `floor` :) Еще - приведение к `int` отбрасывает дробную часть.